# Using unix socket for subprocess stdin, stdout, stderr

Tags: python, sockets, stdout, stdin, stderr

I'd like to wrap a game server process in Python so I can use a socket to access the console from other programs.  I'd like to be able to read stdout, stderr and be able to send in data to stdin to communicate to the server with a socket.

Thus far I have tried something like this:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX)
sock.setblocking(0)
sock.bind('server.sock')
sock.listen(5)
sock.accept()
fd = sock.makefile()

proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=fd, stdout=fd, stderr=fd)
```

I can connect to the `server.sock` unix socket, but no data is ever read when I expect the server to have output.

Comment: This doesn't look like the full program. What is args set to?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ignore the return value of `sock.accept()`: it returns a tuple, the first item of which is the *connected* socket object.  It is different from `sock`, whose only purpose is to accept (possibly several) connections.  You need to call `makefile()` on this connected socket object instead of on the original `sock`.

Comment: Using sock.accept() in that order will not work unless there's an actually connect request waiting to be accepted.  How can I spin up the process so that a connecting socket starts receiving I/O from the already running process?